# Add NSView to Unit3d view

Tags: macos, plugins, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity3d. I am writing osx plugin for Unity3d. 
And I try to add NSView(webview) inside UnityView

```
NSWindow *mainWindow = [[NSApplication sharedApplication] mainWindow];
    NSRect rect = NSMakeRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
        webView = [[WebView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
        webView.hidden = NO;
        [webView setAutoresizingMask:(NSViewHeightSizable|NSViewHeightSizable)];
        [webView setPolicyDelegate:self];
        [self setVisibility:YES];
        [self loadURL:"http://google.com"];

    [[mainWindow contentView]addSubview:webView];
```

But when i build project i does not see my webview(osx application). But when i resize window I see webview, but then it disappeared.

Link to app file https://www.dropbox.com/s/s9t6epajpji53wy/example%20app.app.zip?dl=0

Where square is texture(where should present webview) And press 1 - than will be created web view

Comment: You might want to take a few minutes and read through [lazy coders](http://thelazycoder.com/videotutorials/unity-plugins-on-mac-osx) implementation of a nswindow

Comment: This is do not decide my problem, I add link to example project.